# jQuery Checking Cookie and Hide Content Based on Value and Data Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a list of coupons that all have data attributes (data-coupon) on a page. I am currently setting cookies and storing the value to pair with the data-coupon value (1 through 4). As of now I have it working but the code I wrote is very repetitive and since I am not too well versed in jQuery and Cookies I was hoping to come here and see if someone could point me in the right direction on how to simplify this script. Ideally, I'd like to be able to match the cookie, selected coupon, and its value with the corresponding data attribute of the coupon that it matches with and only show that coupon on page refresh while hiding the others. But currently, I'm using this method below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //if cookie is set, display only that container
  if($.cookie('selected-coupon') == '1') {
    $('.coupons').hide();
    $('#coupon1').show();
    $('#coupon1').removeClass('hide col-sm-6').addClass('col-sm-12');
  }
  if($.cookie('selected-coupon') == '2') {
    $('.coupons').hide();
    $('#coupon2').show();
    $('#coupon2').removeClass('hide col-sm-6').addClass('col-sm-12');
  }
  if($.cookie('selected-coupon') == '3') {
    $('.coupons').hide();
    $('#coupon3').show();
    $('#coupon3').removeClass('hide col-sm-6').addClass('col-sm-12');
  }
  if($.cookie('selected-coupon') == '4') {
    $('.coupons').hide();
    $('#coupon4').show();
    $('#coupon4').removeClass('hide col-sm-6').addClass('col-sm-12');
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that changes between the conditions is the `id` you select. As that matches the value of the cookie, just concatenate them together:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.coupons').hide();
  $('#coupon' + ($.cookie('selected-coupon') || '1')).show().removeClass('hide col-sm-6').addClass('col-sm-12');
});
```

Note that the `||` is used to default the value to `1` if no cookie is present. I'd also suggest hiding the `.coupons` elements in CSS instead of JS in order to avoid the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Comment: If I already have logic in place below this for if the cookie isn't present, won't this overwrite that?

Comment: It wouldn't overwrite it, but it would make the purpose of it redundant.